# Web application Task Parallel threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, task-parallel-library

I wrote a simple application that sends out bulk emails.  It uses a parallel foreach loop to send emails via system.net.mail.  The parallel foreach loop is surrounded by a for loop which was chunking up a 15000 email list into 20 each and waiting 1 second by a thread.sleep.  I set the executiontimeout to 7200 in the web config.  This application should have been done within an hour easy.  My question is - why did the application take over a hour to complete.  Is it waiting for the threads to complete or something?  How can I make it stop?  It eventually timed out through another timer - but???  I am new to threading - I am having a hard time trying to wrap my head around this one.

```
 var chunk = emailList.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / Convert.ToInt32(chunkSize))
                      .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToList())
                        .ToList();
                        for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i > 0)
                            {
                                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(waitTime))
                                {
                                    //mre.WaitOne(Convert.ToInt32(waitTime));
                                    //mre.Reset();
                                    Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(waitTime));
                                }
                            }

                            Parallel.ForEach(chunk[i], email =>
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    MailMessage em = new MailMessage();
                                    em.From = new MailAddress(tbEmailFrom.Text);
                                    em.To.Add(email.ToString().Trim());
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmailCC.Text))
                                    {
                                        em.CC.Add(tbEmailCC.Text);
                                    }
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmailBC.Text))
                                    {
                                        em.Bcc.Add(tbEmailBC.Text);
                                    }

                                    em.ReplyToList.Add(tbReplyTo.Text);
                                    em.Body = tbEmailBody.Text;
                                    em.IsBodyHtml = true;
                                    em.Subject = tbSubject.Text;
                                    em.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
                                    em.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                                    using (SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient())
                                    {

                                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpServer))
                                        {
                                            sm.Host = Host.SMTPServer;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            sm.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                                            sm.Host = smtpServer;
                                            sm.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                                        }

                                        sm.Send(em);
                                    }

                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                                }
                                catch (SmtpException smtp)
                                {
                                    errorList.Add(email.ToString() + "<br />");
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    errorList.Add(email.ToString() + "<br />");
                                    Exceptions.LogException(ex);
                                }

                            });




 }
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Using `Thread.Sleep` is almost always a bad idea, are you trying to throttle network usage or something?

Comment: posted the code - yes trying to throttle.  The test was successful except for the long wait.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, and are you willing to use a 3rd party DLLs if they are free and help you get the job done?

Comment: Net 4.0.  Don't know why I would need any third party dlls?

Comment: read this article https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sending-bulk-emails-with-tasks-parallel-foreach/. I believe, it will help you.

Comment: The article does not explain why my web application took so long?  Just another way to code what I did.